# How to avoid both divs from touching the top border?

Tags: html, css, angular

CSS:

```
.TopLeft
{
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.TopRight
{
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.Info
{

  background-color: #FF6347;
  border:   10px solid CornflowerBlue;
  padding:  30px;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf = "blogs.length == 0" >
    <h1 class = "Info"> No blogs to display! </h1>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf = "blogs.length > 0">

    <div class = "Info"> Existing {{blogs.length}} blogs are as follows: </div>

        <ng-container *ngIf = "view.value === 'gridView'" >
            <ul>
                <div class = "gridView">
                <ng-container *ngFor = "let checkboxesBlog of getCheckboxes_FormGroup.controls; let i = index;" >
                    <ng-container *ngIf = "checkboxesBlog.controls.visible.value === true"; class = "blogList">

                        <div class= "pqr1" >

                                <!-- pre represents new line -->
                                <pre routerLink = "/editor/{{checkboxesBlog.controls.blogTitle.id}}">{{checkboxesBlog.controls.blogTitle.value }}</pre>

                                <pre>Creation date: {{checkboxesBlog.controls.blogTitle.creationDate}}</pre>

                                <ng-container [formGroup] = "checkboxesBlog">
                                    <input type   = "checkbox"
                                           formControlName = "checkboxValue"
                                           (click) = "onCheckboxClicked( i )">
                                </ng-container>
                        </div>

                    </ng-container>

                </ng-container>

              </div>
            </ul>
        </ng-container>
```

It results in this:

[image]

***How to stop `Info` class from touching the upper border?***

In this example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFVBV2TBBD5Q

They are not using any extra padding or space or extra div, so what is it that are doing and I can also do such that divs automatically don't sit on each other's head?

Comment: Please provide HTML snippet from what is sent to the browser, rather than the view that is in your project. Or at least tag your question with the name of the web framework you are using.

Comment: @RobJarvis I am sorry, I forgot to tag it Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not put margin on border, but you can emulate border with another div to act like one in your case.

You also need one more div to give space between your border and inner div.  That space is defined in `padding-top:  5px;` that gives the 5px space, and you need `margin: 5px;` on that to cover other sides. Both values need to update when you customize that space.

```css
.Info
{
  background-color: #FF6347;
  padding:  30px;
  }
.border {
  background-color: CornflowerBlue;
  padding:  10px;
}

.space {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top:  5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "border">
<div class = "space">
    <div class = "Info"> Existing {{blogs.length}} blogs are as follows: </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

To answer the added question, example in W3 you provided uses `H2` element in  `content div`, that alone is already 2 elements, H2 has by default its own margin, like any other H* element, same goes for `footer` and that is where margin and spaces come from.

Other difference is that you are trying to make space between border and its own element, `border` is part of that same element and it wraps around it, and it can not detach from it. This is why I resorted to emulate it in another `div` that wraps around first one. 
I had attempts to downsize the background of `info div` but I couldn't do it, witch does not mean I didn't miss something, i did try all sort of things.

Also in example from W3 none of the element uses border that wraps around it, so your example does not really represent your problem as elements that have space between them are not inside of each other.

But it did point me into another direction that uses only 2 elements not 3 as my first example, witch gives `background-color` to inside element so it can be manipulated:

(all this is coming just from my experience and I'm not expert, so maybe someone else may explain or do it different)

```css
.Info
{
  border:   10px solid CornflowerBlue;
  padding:  30px;
}
.inside{
background-color: #FF6347;
padding:30px;
margin:-25px -30px -30px -30px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "Info">
<div class = "inside">  Existing {{blogs.length}} blogs are as follows: 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFVBV2TBBD5Q They are not using any extra div or padding. Why is my code requiring extra divs and padding?

Comment: Now I tried all this in my program and it is working very properly. Thank you very much for your help again.

Comment: Please see this example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFZBR6O79QVG Here there isn't any h1 or p tags. Still divs are not sitting on each other's heads. No extra borders are required in this case. Please explain why.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl divs are  literary sitting on each other's heads... As you can see two lines in middle seems double width because its two borders sitting together of two elements. I am confused now what are you even trying to achieve, are my snippets (examples) even result as what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Seems I didn't describe properly. In the image which I have put in the question, the blue border of info div is on the top and the pink topleft and top right are also on the top. Both those divs are on the top. Whereas in the link above, one div is on the top and the other in on its bottom.